# Does it work to install .NET rollup patches before .NET 4.7?

Tags: windows, security, windows-update, .net-framework, patch

Recently, Microsoft issued multiple patches to .NET.  The patches are in roll-ups and are applied to various popular versions of .NET *as well as* the new .NET 4.7.

But what if:

1. a system does not have .NET 4.7 installed
2. the .NET rollup patches *(described above)* are applied
3. .NET 4.7 is later installed

**When step #3 is eventually performed, will the patches previously applied in step #2 somehow be applied to .NET 4.7?**

BTW from what I can tell, this is going to be the typical order of operations for many/most systems.

Please include the Windows version number to which your answer applies.  Thanks.

Comment: So you're asking if the .NET 4.7 installer includes the patches for the previous versions? Which previous version(s)? .NET 3? Earlier versions of .NET 4?

Comment: This is easy to try yourself: Install patch on non-4.7 PC, install 4.7, run Windows Update to see if patch is offered again. My guess is yes...what is there to patch if the program isn't installed to begin with?

Comment: @music2myear Not quite what I'm asking... the .NET 4.7 installer does not include patches to previous versions, to my knowledge.  Separate from the installer, MS is offering a .NET patch rollups that apply to multiple 4.x versions.  IOW, each patch rollup applies to all recent 4.x versions.

Comment: There's no question mark in what you just typed. You made three statements and didn't ask anything in the clarification, so I can still only guess. Are you asking if any given roll-up installer will include patches for all .NET 4.x versions?

Comment: Are you asking, effectively, if you can skip step 2 if you were planning to do step 3? Please think carefully about what you're asking, and then use the EDIT button to clarify your question.

Comment: I have performed an edit.  Thank you for your interest.

Comment: “the .NET 4.7 installer does not include patches to previous versions” patches to previous versions of .net are not applicable to 4.7

Comment: “the .NET rollup patches (described above) are applied” when a .net vulnerability is fixed each applicable.net release gets its own patch only those applicable software are installed.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks.  For your first comment, I reply "exactly". :)  To your second comment, I reply "MS is now combining .NET patches into rollups that are applied to multiple versions of .NET".

Comment: My research into .NET vulnerabilities indicates that each version receives its own kB which makes sense since 4.7 and previous versions of .net can be installed side-by-side.  The rollups still contains individual patches for specific versions of .net.